# Can I deploy an index.html with redirects to multiple locations with Azure?

Tags: azure

I have an AngularJS SPA application that uses an Azure C# computer instance for a back-end web-api.

Currently the index.html and the javascript files for the application are sourced from Amazon AWS. This works fine but I have an issue with SEO and if the user tries to do directly to a page without going through the index then it will return an error.

Here for example this link:

```
 http://www.example.com/home/about
```

works good when the user has first entered www.example.com but it fails as a stand alone URL as when a user enters www.example.com/home/about page it won't load the index.html and the AngularJS code, javascript etc will not be loaded:

Now I am thinking that the only solution for me might be to leave the index.html on the Azure web server and have some kind of redirect.

I'd appreciate some advice from anyone who has a configuration like this. Specifically

- How can I do the redirect, what would I need to add to my web config
- Is there a way I could geo locate the same index.html file in different regions and have users sent to the index.html in the region nearest to them.

Answer (score 2):

let me try to help on the first question when your user try to navigate to "http://www.example.com/home/about" and not go thru index.html

in this case i think you will need to implement "deep linking" in your SPA. try to do a [search](http://www.bing.com/search?FORM=UP97DF&PC=UP97&q=deep%20linking%20in%20AngularJS%20SPA) from search engine you will find plenty of tutorials.

To your second question, one solution is, you will need to have Azure Instance in different region and use Traffic manager to distribute request to the nearest instance, and each instance you will need to implement logic to get "index.html" from proper AWS region.